# Regex nested UL from html in C#

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have a nested ul, li list in my html. How can i get the regex from ul to the end of ul node. In this example below i need to get 2 matches.

First one should be

```
<ul>
    <li>This is First List</li>
    <li>This is Second List</li>
    <ul>
        <li>This is Second UL First List </li>
        <li>This is Second UL Second List </li>
    </ul>
    <li>This is Third List</li> 
</ul>
```

and the second one should be

```
<ul>
        <li>This is Next List</li>
        <ul>
            <li>This is Test </li>
        </ul>
        <li>This is Third List</li> 
        <ul>
            <li>This is Test </li>
        </ul>
 </ul>
```

My HTML code:

```
<html>
<p> This is First Paragraph </p>
<ul>
    <li>This is First List</li>
    <li>This is Second List</li>
    <ul>
        <li>This is Second UL First List </li>
        <li>This is Second UL Second List </li>
    </ul>
    <li>This is Third List</li> 
</ul>
<p> This is Second Paragraph </p>   

<ul>
    <li>This is Next List</li>
    <ul>
        <li>This is Test </li>
    </ul>
    <li>This is Third List</li> 
    <ul>
        <li>This is Test </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use a regex to parse HTML. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4664094

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2307070)

Comment: You could try HTML Agility Pack (https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com). As noted by previous posters don't use RegEx.

Comment: There is also a .NET Core version here: https://github.com/linezero/HtmlAgilityPack

Answer (score 0):

You can match nested constructs with [.NET Balancing Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html). This feature basically adds the concept of a stack, which can be pushed/popped `(<NestedUL>...)` and `(<-NestedUL>...)`, and then tested for at the end of the pattern via the last conditional which includes only an empty lookahead guaranteed to fail the pattern `(?(NestedUL)(?!))`:

```
var input =
    @"<html>
    <p> This is First Paragraph </p>
    <ul>
        <li>This is First List</li>
        <li>This is Second List</li>
        <ul>
            <li>nested list #1 inside first parent UL</li>
            <li>This is Second UL Second List </li>
        </ul>
        <li>This is Third List</li> 
    </ul>
    <p> This is Second Paragraph </p>   

    <ul>
        <li>This is Next List</li>
        <ul>
            <li>nested list #1 inside second parent UL</li>
        </ul>
        <li>This is Third List</li> 
        <ul>
            <li>nested list #2 inside second parent UL</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    </html>";
                var pattern = "<ul>(?:(?<NestedUL><ul>)|(?<-NestedUL></ul>)|.)+?(?(NestedUL)(?!))</ul>";
                var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
            }
```

*note the *non-greedy* quantifier on the repeated alternation `+?` - if this was greedy, the pattern would happily consume both ul's with a single match.